# Getting two variables in the URL with htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, get, methods

What way it is to be to get two GET methods in the URL by htaccess?

```
RewriteRule ^adm/(.*)$ adm.php?mode=$1
```

I've used that for the example URL:

```
http://www.domain.com/adm/thismode
```

Now I want to get two methods like:

```
http://www.domain.com/adm/thismode/othermode
```

I've tried this:

```
RewriteRule ^adm/(.*)$/(.*)$ adm.php?mode=$1&othermode=$2
```

But doesn't seem to work... how do I get it to do that?

**EDIT:**

$mode1 = $_GET['mode'];

$mode2 = $_GET['othermode'];

Like this...

**EDIT AGAIN:**

```
http://www.domain.com/adm/generated/pass/6z9c4q9k8p
```

Right... this is the URL it has to do

And in the PHP it has this:

```
if($mode == "generated")
```

I want the PHP to see if the mode is set in the URL and the generated password is the other GET

I put the htaccess as this way:

```
RewriteRule ^adm/(.*)/(.*)$ adm.php?mode=$1&generated=$2
```

The PHP will also grab the generated password in the URL and display it on the page.

Comment: I think you need to describe what you need with a term other than "GET methods" seeing as GET method means something else: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_methods

Answer (score 10, accepted):

what's the problem you're having now  Seems like Richard got you what you needed?

Using your example URL:

```
http://www.domain.com/adm/generated/pass/6z9c4q9k8p
```

and the following in your .htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^adm/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$ adm.php?mode=$1&generated=$2&pass=$3
```

then you can do:

```
$mode1 = $_GET['mode'];
$generated = $_GET['generated'];
$pass = $_GET['pass'];
if ( $mode1 == 'generated' && $generated == 'pass' ) 
    echo $pass;
```

or was that not your question?

Answer (score 6):

In Perl compatible RegExs a `$` is an anchor, which denotes "the end". So remove the `$` from the middle of your pattern, after `^adm/(.*)`:

```
RewriteRule ^adm/(.*)/(.*)$ adm.php?mode=$1&othermode=$2
```

Comment: +1, but escaping the forward slashes in the context above is not necessary (also the dollar sign can be left out entirely).

Comment: I've edited the post again... need some help on the other bit

Comment: @ChristopheD - Cool! Thanks; I'll remove the "escape the slashes" part.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing complex regular expressions in the .htaccess, I would just use a simple

```
RewriteCond $1 !^adm\.php
RewriteRule ^adm/(.*)$ adm.php/$1 [L]
```

and work with `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` inside `adm.php` so you can handle any kind of complex URL which starts with `adm` without changing the .htaccess.